# iTunes Connect Screenshot doesn't accept iPad PRO screenshots

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, app-store-connect, screenshot

My iPad PRO simulator is not scaling from iPad AIR simulator, I have the launch screen storyboard. So I took a screenshot from the iPad PRO simulator and tried to upload it onto screenshots in iTunes Connect but it gave me a warning that the size was wrong. Why is the iPad PRO simulator use the incorrect size for iTunes Connect?

Comment: Did you create a screenshot by pressing command - s (dumps the png onto the desktop) or are you using the OS X system command (command - shift - 4)

Comment: Make sure the simulator window is at 100% scale before taking the screenshot.

Comment: I completely forgot about command-s. But I click on File --> Save Screenshot. I use the 25% scale for iPad PRO simulator, does it really make a difference? I can't see everything with 100% scale.

Comment: Yeah, the scale makes a difference for the iPad Pro, I just confirmed @rmaddy He should write in the answer.

Comment: It only needs to be at 100% when you take the screenshot. Make it 25%, get what you want in place, make it 100%, take the screenshot, and then go back to 25%.

Comment: You guys are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If you need a full-resolution screenshot, be sure to first turn off the 'Optimize Rendering for Window Scale' option in the Debug menu.  When that is on, the framebuffer (from which the screenshot is dumped) matches the pixel dimensions of the scaled window.

Comment: Oh, that's a really nice find!

Comment: Since you work at Apple, how do I add a 167x167 iPad PRO app icon in Xcode 7.1 since there's no app icon space in images.assets?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 9.1 you no longer have a simple scale option in the simulator. This means that on many devices the full screen view will have much of the simulator off screen thus blocking app controls - like the tabbar - making it impossible to select tabs. To override this, after switching off 'Optimize Rendering ...' above, unclick 'Show Device Bezels'. You can then use the simulator while re-selecting the 'Show Device Bezels' for the screenshots.