# Taking screenshots in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am currently trying to take screenshots of my app in order to publish it to the App Store.

The problem is when I take a screenshot on the iPhone 6S simulator (4,7 inch) and upload it to the iTunes Connect it says the dimensions are too small (**375x667**) and they are required to be at least **750x1334**.

Am I taking the screenshots the wrong way or is my Xcode simulator incapable of taking screenshots at high dimensions?

Comment: Are you taking screen shots from a real device using the Device Panel or are you using the Simulator?

Comment: Maybe help you this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487157/where-does-the-ios-simulator-save-screen-shots

Comment: Press command+1 then command+s, you will get the screenshot of desired size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just did it. You have to set the scale to 100% first and than take the screenshot.

Answer (score 97):

Try this one! The screenshots are saved on the Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Hey @NitzanWilnai, it is possible to bind it to a keyboard shortcut via the macOS System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts utility whereby you would add a new App Shortcut for Xcode. You must match the Menu Title exactly as you see it in Xcode. In my case, the value is `Take Screenshot of [REDACTED]'s iPhone`, which I bound to `^⌘S`

Comment: Where does the screenshot get saved?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky On the desktop

Answer (score 26):

When running in simulator, pressing `CMD`+`S` saves a Screenshot of the active simulator to the Desktop.

With a real device connected and focus to the Xcode window you can click the menu
 `Debug` > `View Debugging` > `Take Screenshot of [Devicename]`
This Screenshot is saved to the Desktop too.

Answer (score 6):

Press Command - S, you will get screenshot in the same size of the actual sim device.

Also, If you want to generate nice screen shot sor App Store, I use this web site (https://launchkit.io/). (Free version)

Comment: They broke something in the last Simulator, so now it takes scaled screenshots with Cmd + S for some reason, which is exactly the problem the OP was having.

Comment: Wow, not cool. 
Fastlane is also great source of tool to get screenshots.
https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot

Comment: you can uncheck Optimize Rendering for Window Scale in the debug menu and the screenshots will be the right scale again. Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009781/itunes-connect-screenshot-doesnt-accept-ipad-pro-screenshots

Answer (score 3):

Set **Xcode shortcut from Preferences...** for the screenshot of the active device.

> Go to Xcode >> Preferences... >> Key Bindings >> View Debugging-Take
>   Screenshot of Active Device (Debug Menu) >> Set your custom shortcut.

Set your custom shortcut, I set **ctrl+cmd+alt+S**

Answer (score 2):

You also need to uncheck "Optimize Rendering for Window Size" on the simulator: [image]

Steps to get correctly sized screenshots for the app store:

1. Open the app in the simulator (6s Plus is 5.5")
2. Uncheck "Optimize Rendering for Window Size" on the simulator.
3. Press Cmd+1 to set size to "Physical Size"
4. Press Cmd+S to save a screenshot to desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the Simulator menubar option to capture the screenshot !

Comment: Yes. It works to upload the images to app store. Do you find difficulty in this process?

Comment: @zeetmohanty, The OP knows about it. The last Xcode/Simulator is broken. See my comment to Franck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of these things worked for me.  My problem was that I was not using the iPhone X simulator to take the screenshots.  `Cmd + s` worked once I switched.